# Combination of equals and not equals in Django filter

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to filter using a not equals in a Django object filter like the following:

```
peculiarties = MetricAssociation.objects.filter(metric=metric, specifics != null)
```

This is not working cause of the !=. However, I have done a lot of research on this using `exclude()` etc but cannot seem to find anything that allows both true and false filtering in one Django Query.

Any suggestions how to do both True (metric = metric) and False (specifics != null)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) for such a scenario,

```
from django.db.models import Q
peculiarties = MetricAssociation.objects.filter(Q(metric=metric) & ~Q(specifics=None))
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't need Q objects. This is built in to [Django querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#isnull).

```
peculiarties = MetricAssociation.objects.filter(metric=metric, specifics__isnull=False)
```

Note that there is a double underscore.

Answer (score 1):

Or a combination of filter and exclude.

```
MetricAssociation.objects.filter(metric=metric).exclude(specifics=None)
```